# iOS - How to add subview on top of tableView cell without be covering by the previous Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview

I have a tableivew, I want to add a coachmark on top of the tableview cell. and this coachmark is like a popup.
what I did is uncheck the **clip to bonds** in this tableview cell so it appeared correctly.

but what happened is when I scroll up/bottom this popup is covered by the previous tableview cell.
so any idea how to solve this issue with making the cell background clear because those cells are colored.

Comment: Can you show any Photo what its appear and paste code how you set in to cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use followings methods to change z axis distance for your coachmark view

> bringSubviewToFront(_:)

> sendSubviewToBack(_:) on coachmark or others cells

Example:

```
cell.contentView.bringSubviewToFront(coachmark)
```